# Swift - Snap collectionview cells to center when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to make a slideshow using a collection view . Everything is working fine but when I wanted to make the cells center when the user scrolls I didn't know how to, so I searched online and I found this amazing solution form : https://github.com/damienromito/CollectionViewCustom 
but the problem as you can see from the screen shots is that when I remove the header and footer margins the cells aren't shaping to center anymore and in my design these margins shouldn't exist. Can you please help me figure this out . Thank you :

with margins :

[image]

[image]

without margins :

[image]

this is the code that handles where to scroll :

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let pageWidth = Float(itemWidth + itemSpacing)
    let targetXContentOffset = Float(targetContentOffset.pointee.x)
    let contentWidth = Float(collectionView!.contentSize.width  )
    var newPage = Float(self.pageControl.currentPage)

    if velocity.x == 0 {
        newPage = floor( (targetXContentOffset - Float(pageWidth) / 2) / Float(pageWidth)) + 1.0
    } else {
        newPage = Float(velocity.x > 0 ? self.pageControl.currentPage + 1 : self.pageControl.currentPage - 1)
        if newPage < 0 {
            newPage = 0
        }
        if (newPage > contentWidth / pageWidth) {
            newPage = ceil(contentWidth / pageWidth) - 1.0
        }
    }

    self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(newPage)
    let point = CGPoint (x: CGFloat(newPage * pageWidth), y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)
    targetContentOffset.pointee = point
}
```

and this is where I deleted the margins :

```
   func setup() {


        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        itemWidth =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width - collectionMargin * 2.0

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        //layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionMargin, height: 0)
        //layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionMargin, height: 0)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .green
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = itemSpacing
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView?.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but where exactly are these margins? I can't tell the difference between the with/without margins photos other than the location of item 2.

Comment: @Dopapp when i uncomment these two lines : //layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionMargin, height: 0)         //layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionMargin, height: 0 , i get that space on the left of item 1, that's what am talking about, and as i said I don't want that space

Comment: So you want item 1 to be flush to the right? (Personally, I think it looks better centered)